# Bind values in property file dynamically using Spring

Tags: spring

In my web application i have a scenario like i need to read the values from property file and the value has to be updated dynamically in spring bean. I have created the key value pair as follows,

```
message1=Hi {0} welcome. Your last signed in was {1}
```

How to substitute the values for {0} and {1}. I have read the value using property place holder configurer in spring.

Comment: Don't read the file with a property placeholder configured use a `MessageSource` together with the `<spring:message />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with `MessageSource`

In your applicationContext add:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In your javacode you can write:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
//...
String name = context.getMessage("message1", new Object[] { "user XY", "05.05.2010" }, Locale.US);
```

---

You even can use different message.properties files for different languages: Then you have to name these files: [filename]_[languageCode] (i.e. `messages_en_US.properties` or `messages_de_DE.properties`). And change your 3rd parameter of the `getMessage` method.